# indexOf() backslash returns -1 javascript

Tags: javascript, indexof, backslash

Why javascript for

`'aaaaa\bb'.indexOf('\\')`

returns

`-1`?

I would expect 5, but b i getting that. It really doesn't read backslash as a symbol but it reads it as an escaped character?

Comment: because it would have to be 'aaaaa\\bb' `\b` is a backspace

Comment: becasue \b escaped b.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The backslash in the search string (`'aaaaa\bb'`) disappears when the string constant is parsed; the JavaScript parser *always* reads a single backslash in a string constant as an escape. You have to double it, just like you do in the string you pass to `.indexOf()`.

In your case, `\b` is an escape for the backspace control character. Even in the case of something like `\q`, which is not a "special" character, the backslash is basically ignored.

Answer (score 0):

As already said it is interpreted a control character by the Javascript parser.
If you use the spread syntax to create an array you will get a `\b` as a single element instead of two elements `\` and `b`

```js
 str = 'aaaaa\bb';
 console.log([...str]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `\b` represents the backspace control character and is ignored when you `console.log` your string.

```js
const str = '1234\bb';
console.log(str);
```

So there is no backslash in your string, and `indexOf` returns -1.

```js
const str = 'aaaaa\bb';
console.log(str.indexOf('\\'));
```

If you want to encode a backslash, you will have to escape it, using `\` itself:

```js
const str = 'aaaaa\\bb';
console.log(str);
console.log(str.indexOf('\\'));
```